Coding and Plotting Haar Wavelet
I am trying to plot Haar Wavelet function using the code below:
#define the t variable
#define the range of the time domain
L  = 10
#Define the number of points in the time domain
n  = 100
#define the time variable
t  = np.linspace(-L,L,num=n)

#define the Haar function
def Haar(t,a,b,c): 
    if a <= t <= b:
        return 1.0
    elif b <= t <= c:
        return -1.0 
    else:
        return 0.0 

psi_haar = Haar(t,0,1/2,1)

But an error message keeps appearing every time I run the code.
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Any help debugging the code would be appreciated.
Thanks.
